# How to create custom cells 100% programmatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, user-interface

I am trying to build a TableView programmatically, but I cannot get a basic standard label to display; all I see is basic empty cells. Here's my code:

TableView Cell:

```swift
class TableCell: UITableViewCell {

    let cellView: UIView = {
       let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        return view
    }()

    let labelView: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Cell 1"
        return label
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setup() {
        addSubview(cellView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cellView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            cellView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            cellView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            cellView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)])
        cellView.addSubview(labelView)
    }
}
```

Data Source:

```swift
class TableDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    let cellID = "cell"

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! TableCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

And this is the VC:

```swift
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let dataSource = TableDataSource()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(TableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: dataSource.cellID)
        tableView.dataSource = dataSource
    }
}
```

I am trying to keep the code as basic as possible for future references. I've set various breakpoints to see what could go wrong, but they all check out. Could it be the constraints that are wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should be adding views to `contentView`, not directly to cell. You don't have any constraints for your label. Ideally use `backgroundView` instead of covering the whole cell with a red subview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several errors in your cell.

1. Add subviews to `contentView`, not directly to cell:

   ```
   contentView.addSubview(cellView)
   cellView.addSubview(labelView)
   ```

   The same is necessary for constraints:

   ```
   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
       cellView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
       cellView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
       cellView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
       cellView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor)
   ])
   ```
2. Views created in code need to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`,

   ```
   let cellView: UIView = {
      let view = UIView()
       view.backgroundColor = .systemRed
       view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       return view
   }()

   let labelView: UILabel = {
       let label = UILabel()
       label.text = "Cell 1"
       label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       return label
   }()
   ```

   3. There are no constraints for your label.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea about the `contentView`. Worked like a charm.

Comment: @fankibiber The reason for `contentView` is the fact that the cell contains other views, e.g. `backgroundView`, `selectedBackgroundView`, action buttons ("Delete"), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your constraints don't work, because you need to change `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` for `cellView` in your `setup()`:

```
    func setup() {
        addSubview(cellView)
        cellView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cellView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            cellView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            cellView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            cellView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)])
        cellView.addSubview(labelView)
    }
```